# Iframe Local Storage

Tags: javascript, iframe

Could you please suggest on next case?

I have js application which is using localStorage

When I open this app in iframe of other domain it fails because of browser policy which restrict js to use same domain localStorage

So when app is being loaded via iframe it is trying to reach localStorage of parent instead of its own localStorage

Is there any way to force application to use his own localStorage in case when app is loaded via iframe?

Comment: no. reason: security.

Answer (score 1):

Use sessionStorage instead.
Every browser tab has a seperate session object, which is destroyed on tab closure. Whereas LocalStorage is per domain.